# How do i use vba to filter a set of data by using filtering values one by one

Tags: excel, vba

So I was trying to write a VBA code which can filter a set of data. Suppose I have data in excel ranged through column `A` to `G`, and I want my filter to act in column `C`. Now the column `C` contains like `6` unique values. I want to know how the data can be filtered by the values in `C`, one by one. Some kind of looping and selection based on indices is what I want.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17221895/7889129

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through all available autofilter criteria one at a time in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220736/looping-through-all-available-autofilter-criteria-one-at-a-time-in-vba)

Comment: @MaddyNikam   i went through the answers that in the link, the last answer was seems to be a way that is close to what i am looking but i hope a simpler solution can be made. Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub GetUniqueAndCount()
        Dim d As Object, c As Range, k, tmp As String
        dim LastRow as long
            LastRow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        set rng = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
        For Each c In rng
            tmp = Trim(c.Value)
            If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
        Next c
        For Each k In d.keys
            'Write filter code here d(k)
            'Criteria1:= d(k)
        Next k
    End Sub
```

If you want use dictionary with unique values then Try like this